# Using ArcGIS Flex API with Google Places

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, google-places-api, arcgis

Results obtained from Google Places - when shown on a map - must use Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/places/policies

Although ArcGIS API for Flex provides a way to use Tiles from alternate sources - Google do not offer support for calling their Tiles outside of their JavaScript API.

I'm developing a mobile app - so using javascript is out of the question.

How can I satisfy the logo requirements if I cannot load the map tiles?  Is there a way I can do this?

Would Google offer a break/workaround for Flex Developers?

Comment: Not sure I understand why creating a mobile application precludes using JavaScript. In fact, it precludes using Flex which doesn't work on very many mobile devices. JavaScript within a webview is much more likely to work, depending on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question. You can't use Google Places with a non-Google Map, and Google doesn't have a way to use Places with a Flex-based maps app. If you can't switch to JavaScript, you're only option is to not use Google Places.

Comment: This is correct. Or, use Google Places but not a map, Places can be used, as long as it is properly credited, without a map.